# In Swift, how do I force a UITextView in a UITableViewCell to update with correct margins on first load?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

Using Xcode 7.3 here, wanting to adjust my UITextView margins, but it's not working on all instances when my view loads. Only when scrolling table rows off-screen, then back on, do the UITextViews correct themselves.

I'm using this code in a configureCell function for a custom PostCell:

```
self.movieSummary.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(5.0, 10.0), animated: false)
```

**...but it only gets applied to the top row's UITextView on first load!?**

Here are two screenshots which show the problem with the UITextView highlighted in red...

1) On first load: Only the top row is OK. Other rows are misaligned.

[image: On first load: Only the top row is OK. Other rows are misaligned.]

2) After scrolling down and back up: All rows are correctly aligned.

[image: After scrolling down and back up: All rows are correctly aligned.]

How can I force all the rows/cells/UITextViews to update on first load?

EDIT 1: Here's my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = moviePosts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {

        cell.request?.cancel()
        var posterImg: UIImage?
        if let url = post.moviePosterImgPath {
            posterImg = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }
        var bgImg: UIImage?
        if let url = post.movieBgImgPath {
            bgImg = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }
        cell.configureCell(post, posterImg: posterImg, bgImg: bgImg)
        return cell

    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code for cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @AshishKakkad Right.

Comment: @AshishKakkad added.

Comment: You have not added code for the configure cell. and your custom cell file. you have to code inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for removing the insets and padding.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Thanks for the suggestion but including the margin adjustments within cellForRowAtIndexPath - after calling cell.configureCell - still doesn't fix it. I also tried including  `PostCell().movieSummary.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(5.0, 10.0), animated: false)` before the `return PostCell()` in case it was the non-dequeued cells which were at fault, but still I keep getting the unwanted margins on rows 2,3,4 on first load.